# unable to save changes to objects with form.save()

Tags: django

I am writing a control view function `edit_article` to update fields of `title` and `content` of model table `Article`:

To update the title and content, I employed `article=form.save`

```
def edit_article(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ArticleForm(data=request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           article = form.save()
```

It reports error when issue submitting

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'owner_id' cannot be null")
```

I did not change `owner_id`, just keep it as its previous state.

The problem is solved by explicitly re-assign attribute:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        # article = form.save()
        article.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        article.content = form.cleaned_data['content']
        article.save()
```

The model `Article`

```
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (1,  'normal'),
        (0, 'deleted'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField() # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Why `form.save()` failed as a shortcut?

Comment: if that, should manually add `article.owner=article.owner_id`  form.save() @Mate

Comment: the owner was not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update existing record, you should pass instance object of that model to the form.

So your code would change to

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ArticleForm(instance=article, data=request.POST)
...
```